# Angular 5 backend dataservice from localnetwork

Tags: angular, web-services

I am planning to deploy my Angular 5 application which consumes 2 Restful-api for all operations.

```
Angular-app : app.domain.com
Service1 : service1.localhost.com
Service2 : service.localhost.com
```

i don't want these 2 services exposed to public that is why added virtual hosts

right now when i deploy my application to server .. web-services have to be exposed to public for it work. !

e.g.

```
service1.domain.com 
service2.domain.com
```

can't angular deal with services internally . ?

or am i doing something wrong ?

Comment: Angular doesn't really deal with services at all-- it's up to your browser to make the call to `service1.localhost.com`, so as long as your browser can access it, then it should be fine. What error are you having?

Comment: my browser cannot access service1.localhost.com as this is servers local environment.. is there a way i can have Angular communicate to internal services.. and i do not have to make these services accessible to general public.. !

Comment: If you want it to work, the browser will need to be able to communicate with the service, so it will need to be exposed somehow

Comment: ok .. i think that answers my questions.. ! services has to be accessible to users.